# Send PDF file to printer

Tags: php, pdf, printwriter

I am using php_printer.dll extension for printing some text in php and my code for printing is

```
$handle = printer_open("EPSON TM-T82II Receipt");
    printer_start_doc($handle, "My Document");
    printer_start_page($handle);
    $filename='billdoc_260.pdf';
    $fhandle=fopen($filename, 'r');
    $contents = fread($fhandle, filesize($filename));
    fclose($fhandle);
    printer_set_option($handle, PRINTER_MODE, "RAW");
    printer_write($handle,$contents);
    printer_end_page($handle);
    printer_end_doc($handle);
    printer_close($handle);
```

It prints the raw text of pdf file,something like this

```
%PDF-1.3 3 0 obj <> endobj 4 0 obj <> stream xœ•TMOÛ@½çWL
```

I have tried other PRINTER_MODE like emf,text but not working.

Can anyone tell me how can i print pdf from my printer in Windows on WAMP.

Comment: Have you confirmed the extension has loaded successfully ? Eg. phpinfo(); ?

Comment: There're many Postscript printers out there (esp. laser printers) but I wasn't aware of printers that would accept raw PDF. Is that an information you've verified?

Comment: EPSON TM-T82II is not accepting raw pdf. Is there any php code which can do this?

Comment: Please clarify: are you just dumping some random binary file into your printer expecting that it would magically render it as if your ticket printer was a desktop computer with Adobe Reader installed?